# Recreate PDF from path construction operator sequence

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file whose xref and trailer have been overwritten, but have been able to extract the stream objects (`zlib` compressed) and concatenate them into what looks like a sequence of [path construction commands](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/path-construction-and-painting-operators-itext-5/). Here are the first 30 or so lines:

```
0.750000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.750000 0.000000 841.890015 cm
q
q
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 rg
0.000000 0.000000 m
0.000000 1122.520020 l
793.700989 1122.520020 l
793.700989 0.000000 l
h
f*
Q
q
0.000000 48.000000 m
793.700989 48.000000 l
793.700989 1074.719971 l
0.000000 1074.719971 l
0.000000 48.000000 l
h
W* n
q
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg
81.701302 106.030998 m
81.701302 105.721001 81.952400 105.470001 82.262100 105.470001  c
82.571800 105.470001 82.822899 105.721001 82.822899 106.030998  c
82.822899 106.341003 82.571800 106.592003 82.262100 106.592003  c
81.952400 106.592003 81.701302 106.341003 81.701302 106.030998  c
h
81.757301 106.142998 m
81.757301 105.828003 82.012901 105.572998 82.328102 105.572998  c
82.643402 105.572998 82.898903 105.828003 82.898903 106.142998  c
82.898903 106.459000 82.643402 106.713997 82.328102 106.713997  c
82.012901 106.713997 81.757301 106.459000 81.757301 106.142998  c
h
```

Is it possible to reconstruct the original file out of this data (or at least get some idea of what the "drawing" is supposed to represent?

The ideal solution would be a Python library, but I'll be happy with anything that works.